# Effect like inner glow in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, glow

Is there a good way to add an effect like the Photoshop "Inner Glow" effect to an html5 canvas element? I'd prefer it to be without libraries like jQuery or MooTools, but if it's necessary, I'm willing to take a look at them.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/  help?

Comment: @j08691: The inner shadow part looks promising, but I can't quite seem to understand how it works. Could you perhaps give an example of how I could use this to create an inner glow effect?

Answer (score -3):

You can use this css3 property `box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;` The most important attribute here is inset which means inner shadows. You can change other property of attributes as you wish.

Comment: I don't think I can do that here, since I need to apply the inner shadow to a vector object drawn inside the canvas. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.